# How to convert to Java.Lang.Double

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I need to convert to Java.Lang.Double from c# double, int or a string.

Can you help please

```
 if (pResult.Ok && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pResult.Text ))
            {
                var num = Convert.ToInt32(pResult.Text);
                double doub = Convert.ToDouble(num);
                _settingsService.TimeOut = doub;
            }
```

This way I am getting that      java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Answer (score 0):

from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/java.lang.double.-ctor?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9#Java_Lang_Double__ctor_System_String_)

```
new Java.Lang.Double("4.5");
```

Answer (score 0):

I modify your code, please take a look:

```
  var num = Convert.ToInt32(tv1.Text);
  Java.Lang.Double doub = (Java.Lang.Double)Convert.ToDouble(num);
```